# Python 2.7 and unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I'm writing a FAT file system parser. Those who don't know or care much of the topic, FAT filename handling is complex due to extensions to original FAT. A file always has an upper case short name. If the file name is actually short and in upper case, this is the only name the file has, like FOO.TXT.  In contrast, if the filename is longer than 8 characters or the name is a mixture of upper and lower case, there is another name, which is 16-bit unicode.

When constructing a path to a file, it is of course then formed of names of each subdirectory and finally the filename. I need to compare these names to others that come from sqlite database. My comparisons never match and when I looked more deeply at the data, I found the filename strings to be for example

`/FOO/PUP/M^@o^@u^@n^@t^@i^@n^@g^@` ...

as I must use the long, unicode name if one is available. I'm not able to match anything with that string when some characters there are 8 bit and some are 16 bit. I can't get rid of 16 bit unicode, as file names might contain unicode characters.

My suggested solution is to force everything to 16-bit unicode and try to compare those. How do I do this? If I state `unicode("FOO", errors="strict")`, I still get just 8 bit characters (and a crash due to strict as soon as a deleted file with 0xE5 in filename is encountered).

Or is there a way to convert the 16 bit unicode characters to western ascii? This would be even better.

Comment: Better learn to love Unicode. It's not Unicode's fault if you have to juggle character sets, quite the contrary.

Comment: This may be but if I have to combine different character sets due to reasons beyond my control, what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Stop using different character sets, period. Use unicode instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure to do all your comparisons in Unicode.  You'll have to know the original encoding of the data, of course.  Below are four different encodings of the same Unicode characters:

```
#!python3
s1 = b'\xce\xd2\xca\xc7\xc3\xc0\xb9\xfa\xc8\xcb'
s2 = b'\xe6\x88\x91\xe6\x98\xaf\xe7\xbe\x8e\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe4\xba\xba'
s3 = b'\x11b/f\x8e\x7f\xfdV\xbaN'
s4 = b'\x11b\x00\x00/f\x00\x00\x8e\x7f\x00\x00\xfdV\x00\x00\xbaN\x00\x00'

u1 = s1.decode('chinese')
u2 = s2.decode('utf8')
u3 = s3.decode('utf-16le')
u4 = s4.decode('utf-32le')

assert(u1==u2==u3==u4)
```

Convert every text string into Unicode as soon as you can.  Encode it to your preferred encoding when writing the data out again.

Regarding deleted files using `\xE5`, process the raw data to decide if it is a deleted entry first.  No need to process a deleted file into Unicode:

```
if rawdata[0] = 0xE5:
    print('deleted')
else:
    print(rawdata.decode('utf-16le'))
```

**Edit**

I was bored this afternoon, here's a short FAT32 parser.  It doesn't strictly follow the [FAT32 spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg463084)...just enough to illustrate decoding:

```
#!python3
import binascii
import struct

# struct module unpacking formats
SHORT_ENTRY = '<11s3B7HL'     # 12 fields described in FAT32 spec
LONG_ENTRY  = '<B10s3B12sH4s' # 8 fields described in FAT32 spec

# attribute bit values (byte offset 11) 
ATTR_READ_ONLY = 0x01
ATTR_HIDDEN    = 0x02
ATTR_SYSTEM    = 0x04
ATTR_VOLUME_ID = 0x08
ATTR_DIRECTORY = 0x10
ATTR_ARCHIVE   = 0x20
LAST_LONG_ENTRY = 0x40
ATTR_LONG_NAME = ATTR_READ_ONLY | ATTR_HIDDEN | ATTR_SYSTEM | ATTR_VOLUME_ID
ATTR_LONG_NAME_MASK = ATTR_READ_ONLY | ATTR_HIDDEN | ATTR_SYSTEM | ATTR_VOLUME_ID | ATTR_DIRECTORY | ATTR_ARCHIVE

# A few entries from a FAT32 root directory (32 bytes per row)
data = binascii.unhexlify('''
  42 FC 00 69 00 6E 00 6F 00 2E 00 0F 00 D9 6A 00 70 00 67 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 FF FF FF FF 
  01 6C 9A 4B 51 6D 00 61 00 F1 00 0F 00 D9 61 00 6E 00 61 00 20 00 70 00 65 00 00 00 6E 00 67 00 
  4D 41 A5 41 4E 41 7E 31 4A 50 47 20 00 89 6D 8B FE 40 69 43 00 00 C7 7D 8B 3F 03 00 04 06 7D 00 
  41 11 62 2F 66 8E 7F FD 56 BA 4E 0F 00 DC 2E 00 74 00 78 00 74 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 FF FF FF FF 
  46 32 33 33 7E 31 20 20 54 58 54 20 00 4B BA 7B 69 43 69 43 00 00 BB 7B 69 43 00 00 00 00 00 00 
'''.strip().replace(' ','').replace('\n',''))

# Long names are built up from multiple entries, so start empty
raw_long = b''

# Iterate through the 32-byte entries in the data
for offset in range(0,len(data),32):
    raw_entry = data[offset:offset+32]

    # Entries that start with 0xE5 are deleted.
    # An entry that starts with zero indicates no more entries
    if raw_entry[0] == 0xE5: continue
    if raw_entry[0] == 0: break

    if raw_entry[11] & ATTR_LONG_NAME_MASK == ATTR_LONG_NAME:
        # Long entries are found last-to-first and are in three parts
        # per entry.  Concatenate the parts and prepend to entries
        # found so far.
        entry = struct.unpack_from(LONG_ENTRY,data,offset)
        raw_long = entry[1] + entry[5] + entry[7] + raw_long
    else:
        entry = struct.unpack_from(SHORT_ENTRY,data,offset)
        # If the short entry is a volume ID, skip it.
        if entry[2] == ATTR_VOLUME_ID: continue
        # Unpack and decode 8.3 filename in OEM
        # character set.
        basename = entry[0][:8].decode('cp437').rstrip(' ')
        ext = entry[0][8:].decode('cp437').rstrip(' ')
        # Decode and strip the current long name value of padding.
        long_name = raw_long.decode('utf-16le').rstrip('\uffff').rstrip('\0')
        print('{:8}.{:3} - {}'.format(basename,ext,long_name))
        raw_long = b'' # Reset the long name to empty
```

#### Output from an IDE that supports UTF-8 (not the Windows console):

```
MAÑANA~1.JPG - 马克mañana pengüino.jpg
F233~1  .TXT - 我是美国人.txt
```

Comment: @DietrichEpp yes, I've only studied Spanish for a couple of months :)

Answer (score 2):

`unicode(byte_string, errors="strict")` uses the current default encoding to decode the byte string that you pass it. It is very unlikely that this matches the encoding of your data. On a Western Windows, it will typically be iso8859-1, a.k.a. latin-1. But the data in FAT are UTF-16, little-endian.

So you should specify the right encoding explicitly using the `encoding` parameter:

```
unicode (byte_string, errors='strict', encoding='utf_16_le')
```